# retrieve thumbnail image of a browser bookmark

Tags: android, thumbnails, bookmarks, android-browser

I am creating my own android app widget to display browser bookmarks. & i need 2 show the thumbnail image of the bookmarks in my widget.
However the `Browser.BookmarkColumns` doesnt expose the "thumbnail" data.
any idea on how to get the thumbnail image ?
thanx in advance

Comment: Just check the tick mark below the voter to accept it as answer.. The green tick mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does expose the fav icon of the website. But its available in the database if that bookmark url was successfully visited at least once. Also when accessing the internal Android databases use the `managedQuery()` method.

Here is a snippet for accessing the fav icon from db.

```
    Cursor mCur = managedQuery(android.provider.Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI,
        projection, null, null, null);
    mCur.moveToFirst();
    int titleIdx = mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE);
    int urlIdx = mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL);
    int urlIdx = mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.FAVICON);
```

Comment: thats true, but Browser.BookmarkColumns.THUMBNAIL is not exposed :(

Comment: hi userSeven7s .. sorry but i dont knw hw to accept previous answers..           i chkd the browser code, they do access Browser.BookmarkColumns.THUMBNAIL, bt it s nt granted to the developer. I m able to fetch the favicon. Also if i ask for "thumbnail" column data while quering the Browser.BOOKMARKS_URI, i do get the thumbnail data, bt i suppose.. dats not the correct way of doing it...

Comment: You need page thumbnail image.. and  you are able to get it.. Do you have problem in using the image?

Comment: nope.. just the way i am using to get the thumbnail image is not correct way.. tomorrow if android changes its column name from "thumbnail" to smthing else, my code wont work :(  ... Rest no issues.. thanx

Comment: Just take care it doesnt crash when column name changes.. and keep a close watch on android code of your interest..